# Joda time convert ISO8601 GMT to local

Tags: android, jodatime

I have this from my server:

> 2017-04-07T11:00:00.000Z

How can I convert it to local time? Here is my code, but all I got is an exception:)

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2017-04-07T11:00:00.000Z" is malformed at "Z"**

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormat
                .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ") //yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ
                .withLocale(Locale.US);

        DateTime parsed = inputFormatter.parseDateTime(gmtDate);

        DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormat
                .forPattern("HH:mm")
                .withLocale(Locale.US)
                .withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

        return outputFormatter.print(parsed);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
                                   .withLocale(Locale.US);
```

In my case, the result of `outputFormatter.print(parsed)` is `08:00` (my local time, as my default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo`)